# Why in unity i'm getting the warning: You are trying to create a MonoBehaviour using the 'new' keyword?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The full warning message:

> You are trying to create a `MonoBehaviour` using the `new` keyword.  This is not allowed. `MonoBehaviours` can only be added using `AddComponent()`. Alternatively, your script can inherit from `ScriptableObject` or no base class at all

And in both scripts I'm not using the `new` keyword:

The `DetectPlayer` script:

```
public class DetectPlayer : MonoBehaviour 
{
    private int counter = 0;

    private void OnGUI()
    {
        GUI.Box(new Rect(300, 300, 200, 20),
            "Times lift moved up and down " + counter);
    }
}
```

The `Lift` script:

```
public class Lift : MonoBehaviour 
{
    private bool pressedButton = false;
    private DetectPlayer dp = new DetectPlayer();

    private void OnGUI()
    {
        if (pressedButton)
            GUI.Box(new Rect(300, 300, 200, 20), "Press to use lift!");
    }
}
```

Comment: You absolutely are using the `new` keyword: `DetectPlayer dp = new DetectPlayer();`

Comment: Unity doesn't like it when you try to create `MonoBehavior` derived objects using `new`.  It expects you to use `Instantiate` instead for its internal housekeeping to work right.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It is best to not think of MonoBehaviours as C# objects in the traditional sense. They should be considered their own unique thing. They are technically the 'Component' part of the Entity Component System architecture which Unity is based upon.

As such, a MonoBehaviour being a Component, it cannot exist without being on a GameObject. Thus creating a MonoBehaviour with just the 'new' keyword doesn't work. To create a MonoBehaviour you must use AddComponent on a GameObject.

Further than that you cannot create a new GameObject at class scope. It must be done in a method once the game is running, an ideal place to do this would be in Awake.

What you want to do is

```
DetectPlayer dp;

private void Awake()
{
    GameObject gameObject = new GameObject("DetectPlayer");
    dp = gameObject.AddComponent<DetectPlayer>();
}
```

Comment: `What you want to do is` .. **if and only if** you wanted to create a new instance yes. Otherwise what you want to do would actually be to reference the already existing instance of that component .. e.g. either via the Inspector (by exposing a serialized field) or via `FindObjectOfType` etc