# why do we use GetComponent method in unity for accessing other components from our script ,can't we just make an object of that type?

Tags: unity-game-engine

why do we have to access a component from our script using GetComponent method ?
can we make its object instead?

e.g
instead of

```
 Rigidbody rb;
 rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
```

can we use

```
Rigidbody rb = new Rigidbody();
```

and use methods based on that.
will  the be  result same ?

Thankyou.

P.s : I am new to unity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### NO!

*For your usecase though see the very last lines of this answer. ;)*

**It is completely illegal in Unity to use `new` for creating instances of a `Component`!** You will also get a [warning about it in the console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40640553/why-in-unity-im-getting-the-warning-you-are-trying-to-create-a-monobehaviour-u).

For some stupid reason Unity still "allows" to do it though and does only throw a warning instead of an exception. However, that instance just will not "work" since most of things will not be initialized correctly.. and how should it? There is no `GameObject` related to it so what would the use of a `Rigidbody` without according `GameObject` be? - Right, it is absolutely useless ;)

A `Component` can only exist correctly if it is attached to a `GameObject`. Thus, there are only three valid ways of creating instances at runtime:

- Use the constructor of [`GameObject`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject-ctor.html) like e.g.

  ```
   var obj = new GameObject("SomeName", typeof(Rigidbody));
   var rb = obj.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
  ```

  This creates a new GameObject called `SomeName` with only the `Transform` and a `Rigidbody` component attached.
- Use [`Instantiate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html) to either clone an existing GameObject or create an instance from a prefab.

  ```
  [SerializeField] private Rigidbody prefab;

  ...

  var rb = Instantiate (prefab);
  ```
- Use [`AddComponent`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.AddComponent.html) to add a new instance of given component type to an existing `GameObject`. The example from the constructor can also be implemented as

  ```
  var rb = new GameObject("SomeName").AddComponent<Rigidbody>();
  ```

  or in your use case to add that component to the same object your script is attached to

  ```
   var rb = gameObject.AddComponent<Rigidbody>();
  ```

  which probably comes closest to what your code tries to do