# Unity c# I get an error when I try to execute a method

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have this code
first file

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
public class Controller : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Machines machines;
    void Start()
    {
        machines = new Machines();
        machines.ClickSpeedUpgrade();//here I get the error
    }
}
```

second file

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using BreakInfinity;
public class Machines
{
    public void ClickSpeedUpgrade()
    {
        //some code
    }
}
```

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Why do I get this error and how can I fix it?

Comment: We would need to see what is in `ClickSpeedUpgrade` because nothing in `Start` would cause that error

Comment: the call stack error should help you finding where is the problem. Use then breakpoints and debug

Comment: It is [not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40640553/why-in-unity-im-getting-the-warning-you-are-trying-to-create-a-monobehaviour-u) to use `new` in order to create instances of `MonoBehaviour`! Components always need to be attached to an existing `GameObject` -> The only valid options for creating instances is using `someGameObject.AddComponent<Machines>`, `Instantiate(prefabWithMachinesComponent)` or `new GameObject("name", typeof(Machines))` .... does your class need to be a `MonoBehaviour` (=> attached to a certain GameObject and receive Unity messages) at all?

Comment: @derHugo, he is not creating instance of `MonoBehaviour` he is creating an instance of Machines which is not even inherit `MonoBehaviour`, 

Alexandru, your issue is not in the class and new, it is in the `\\some code` part of it.
if you have line numbers, check which line is causing error.